# Реализация мультитенантности в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Изучаю Laravel и мне интересно как реализовать мультитенантность. Например есть пользователи и у них могут быть товары. Нужно чтобы доступ к товарам был только у того пользователя который их создал. Знаю что есть три способа реализации:

1. Для каждого пользователя своя база данных;
2. Все хранится в одной таблице с указанием того кто создал товар;
3. Для каждого пользователя создается своя таблица в единой базе.

В первом случае в настройках пользователь просто подключается к своей базе данных и работает с ней. Для создания всех необходимых таблиц запускаем миграции.

Во втором случае тоже понятно создаем таблицу `products` с полем например `user_create_id`, запускаем миграцию и создаем `traite` и в трейте фильтруем товары по `user_create_id`.

**Собственно ВОПРОС как реализовать третий вариант?** Чтобы при создании нового пользователя в базе создавалась таблица например `user_name_products` и каждый пользователь получал данные именно со своей таблицы в базе.

Comment: Я предлагаю все-таки добить функцию. там совсем немного осталось. надо просто использовать те инструменты, которые упомянуты в комментариях под вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я недавно делал вариант, похожий на 1й и 3й одновременно. Использовались префиксы в подключении к БД.

```
 'connections' => [
        // ...
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('MYSQL_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('MYSQL_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('MYSQL_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('MYSQL_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix_indexes' => true, // важно для миграций, чтобы названия индексов в каждой пользовательской таблице были уникальными
            'prefix' => 'customer_1_', // именно этот параметр!
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
]
```

Важно понимать, каким образом накатывать дальнейшие изменения на все пользовательские таблицы, ведь приходится считаться с тем, что структура модели может быть изменена в будущем, поэтому эти изменения небходимо будет накатить на все пользовательские таблицы модели.

В моем случае получилось разделить пользовательские данные непосредственно по директориям, поэтому и префикс получился из имени директории пользователя. Но это частный случай.

Если делать разные таблицы только для некоторых моделей, то нужно позаботиться о новом подключении к БД, в котором будут все параметры стандартного подключения и динамически добавленный префикс.

### Где добавить новое подключение к БД динамически?

Тут разные варианты: middleware после аутентификации пользователя, сервис-провайдер (опять важно понимать, что уже должен быть аутентифицированный пользователь) или кидать событие после определения пользователя (`auth` middleware переопределить)

### Как указать модели, какое подключение использовать?

Для этого есть статический метод модели `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setConnectionResolver(Resolver $resolver)`. Скорее всего придется немного переписать менеджер подключений к БД

Отправлю копать доки https://github.com/illuminate/database